# SQL Query IP addresses some with 0

Tags: sql

Have a DB with tons of IP's stored along with other data.  Some have 0's preceding the other numbers.  For example, all 3 of the following instances can occur in the DB:

```
12.12.12.12
012.12.012.12
012.012.012.012
```

My first query used like:

```
where ip like '%12.%12.%12.%.12'
```

However, this returns 112.012.112.012, which I wouldn't want.

I tried:

```
where ip like '[0]%12.[0]%12.[0]%12.[0]%.12'
```

but that returns 0 results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which dbms you are using (mysql, mssql / tsql, oracle, postgresql)?

Comment: Pretty sure it's DB2.  I use AQT for the SQL queries.

Comment: What about using HAVING and REPLACE? select ip,REPLACE(ip,"012","12") as ip2 from tablename HAVING ip2 like '12.12.12.12'

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(ip, '^0*12[.]0*12[.]0*12[.]0*12$')
```

Or, if you use `like` you can use:

```
where replace(ltrim(ip, '0'), '.0', '.') like '12.12.12.12'
```

If "00" is a possibility, you'll need another `replace()`.